# Как добавить таблицу в Word файле через C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

Добрый день, подскажите, как можно дописать код? Мне нужно открыть шаблон word-файла, сделать правки и в самом конце добавить таблицу. Первые два пункта сделал, а с добавлением таблицы в конец файла проблемы.

```
public static void createWord() 
{
    wordapp = new Word.Application();
    Object path = @"D:\WorkSpace\Projects\testWord\testWord\testWord\Sh.dot";
    try
    {
        worddocument = wordapp.Documents.Add(ref path, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
        worddocument.Bookmarks["Well"].Range.Text = "asdfasdf";
      //Что нужно писать?
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        worddocument.Close(ref falseObj,ref missingObj,ref missingObj);
        wordapp.Quit(ref missingObj,ref missingObj,ref missingObj);
        worddocument = null;
        wordapp = null;
        //throw new Exception();
    }
    wordapp.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос не соответствует проблеме

Comment: посмотрите [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w1702h4a.aspx)

Comment: Sublihim, уважаемый вы читать умеете? Ну написал же, как добавить в КОНЕЦ файла. Проблема в этом, а не добавлении таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Добавляем параграф в конец документа
var Paragraph = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add();
//Получаем диапазон
var tableRange = Paragraph.Range;
//Добавляем таблицу 2х2 в указаный диапазон
wordApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(tableRange, 2, 2);

//"Приукрашиваем" таблицу, иначе по-дефолту она будет без линий
var table = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Tables[wordApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count];
table.set_Style("Сетка таблицы");
table.ApplyStyleHeadingRows = true;
table.ApplyStyleLastRow = false;
table.ApplyStyleFirstColumn = true;
table.ApplyStyleLastColumn = false;
table.ApplyStyleRowBands = true;
table.ApplyStyleColumnBands = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Создание таблицы:  
Table tb;  /* Если не получится объявить так, то объяви через: public static Table tb;  */
tb = doc.Tables.Add(doc.Paragraphs[doc.Paragraphs.Count].Range, n + 4, 6); /* В паметрах указывается: 1.Место,где она начинается; 2.Кол-во строк; 3.Кол-во столбцов  */
tb.Borders.Enable = 1;//Делаем границы видимыми
```